# Check if all items are the same in a List

Tags: c#, vb.net, list, linq-to-objects

I have a List(Of DateTime) items. How can I check if all the items are the same with a LINQ query? At any given time there could be 1, 2, 20, 50 or 100 items in the list.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (list.Distinct().Skip(1).Any())
```

Or

```
if (list.Any(o => o != list[0]))
```

(which is probably faster)

Comment: Potentially easier to read with "All" instead of "Any". You may also want to use First() instead of [0] in case list access cannot be performed (IEnumerable). if (list.All(o => o == list.First())) { ... }

Comment: `list.Distinct().Skip(1).Any()` is no different than `list.Distinct().Count  != 1` right?

Comment: @GraemeWicksted the whole point of Any() is to be faster if one item is found that DOESN'T match. Then you stop evaluating the list. What IS slightly clearer though is `!(list.Any(o => o != list[0]))` which is true if there are no items that are different from the first one - i.e. if they're all the same

Comment: @Simon_Weaver `Any()` is used to find at least 1 match while `All()` is used to ensure all items match.  In either case, if a non-match is encountered in All or a match is found in Any, they will halt iteration. So `!(list.Any(o => o != list[0]));` and `list.All(o => o == list[0]);` will always have the same iteration count.  Thus both will have about the same execution time. P.S. You are correct, in that `list.Distinct().Skip(1).Any()` is analogous to `list.Distinct().Count != 1` just be aware Count can be slower than Any (possibly even in this case) with > 1 element.

Comment: But count has to iterate over the entire distinct list. If you have more than 2 sets, it's slower.

Answer (score 18):

I created simple extension method mainly for readability that works on any IEnumerable.

```
if (items.AreAllSame()) ...
```

And the method implementation:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///   Checks whether all items in the enumerable are same (Uses <see cref="object.Equals(object)" /> to check for equality)
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="enumerable">The enumerable.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///   Returns true if there is 0 or 1 item in the enumerable or if all items in the enumerable are same (equal to
    ///   each other) otherwise false.
    /// </returns>
    public static bool AreAllSame<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        if (enumerable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enumerable));

        using (var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
        {
            var toCompare = default(T);
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                toCompare = enumerator.Current;
            }

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                if (toCompare != null && !toCompare.Equals(enumerator.Current))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Nice! Just wondering about the empty list implementation. I'm not sure if I would assume that an empty list means "all are the same" - feels like a case for the consumer to handle, so I think I'm going to throw if the list empty. "Are the apples the same? No clue, because there are no apples in the basket"

Comment: This extension does not work in cases where the IEnumerable contains null values. For this case I added `if (toCompare == null && enumerator.Current != null) { return false; }`

Answer (score 15):

My variant:

```
var numUniques = 1;
var result = list.Distinct().Count() == numUniques;
```

Comment: I like this, it's very readable and shows intent compared to the skip1/any solution.

Answer (score 9):

This is an option, too:

```
 if (list.TrueForAll(i => i.Equals(list.FirstOrDefault())))
```

It is faster than `if (list.Distinct().Skip(1).Any())` , and performs similarly as 
  `if (list.Any(o => o != list[0]))`, however, the difference is not significant, so I suggest using the more readable one.

Answer (score 4):

VB.NET version:

```
If list.Distinct().Skip(1).Any() Then
```

Or

```
If list.Any(Function(d) d <> list(0)) Then
```