# c# Check if all strings in list are the same

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if all items are the same in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307172/check-if-all-items-are-the-same-in-a-list)

I have a list:

```
{string, string, string, string}
```

I need to check if all the items in this list are the same then return true, if not return false.

Can i do this with LINQ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
var allAreSame = list.All(x => x == list.First());
```

Comment: Except that `list.First()` is called on every iteration so effectively the list is traversed twice?

Comment: @DavidClarke: Assuming this is LINQ to objects and `list` is just a materialized collection like a list or an array: As `list.First` returns the very first element, it doesn't traverse the list, so: no, the list is only traversed once. Speaking more general, however, you are correct: If `list` would be a non-materialized enumerable, every call to `First` would need to execute all the code (e.g. hitting the database or executing complex Where or OrderBy statements) to get at least the first element. In that case, it would be better, to call `list.First` once and store the result

Answer (score 3):

```
var allAreSame = list.Distinct().Count() == 1;
```

or a little more optimal

```
var allAreSame = list.Count == 0 || list.All(x => x == list[0]);
```

Comment: Actually, for compact lists of primitive types, and even short strings (abbreviations, simple words, etc) I'd have no argument against `list.Distinct().Count() == 1;` versus `list.All(current => current == list.First())` at least for readability's sake.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
    string[] s = { "same", "same", "same" };
    if (s.Where(x => x == s[0]).Count() == s.Length)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Is this lambda expression?

Answer (score 0):

```
var hasIdenticalItems = list.Count() <= 1 || list.Distinct().Count() == 1;
```