# Determine if values are different

Tags: c#, boolean

Let's say I have 4 variables

```
bool value1 = false;
bool value2 = false;
bool value3 = true;
bool value4 = false;
```

and they all don't have the same value (all are true `||` all are false)

I have found 2 approaches, anyway none of them looks easy to understand.

```
bool areDifferent = !(value1 == value2 == value3 == value4);
```

and

```
bool areDifferent = new[] { value1, value2, value3, value4 }.Distinct().Count() > 1;
```

Question: Is there a other approach, which is better in terms of readability / understandability?

Comment: Both lines look pretty readable and easy to understand to me. This seems like an entirely subjective question and probably not a great one for StackOverflow. You might try to take a moment to understand what the code is doing there if you don't get what they are doing.

Comment: They both looks easy to understand. As alternative you can have `bool areSame` and use `!areSame` to check if there is a difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if all items are the same in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307172/check-if-all-items-are-the-same-in-a-list)

Comment: @Impostor any imperative code is bad in terms of readability/understandability. Also, your first approach is incorrect. Try with `true, false, true, false` to see what is wrong

Comment: `value1 == value2 == value3 == value4` that's not right though. You're comparing the result of the comparisons, not the values themselves.

Comment: Your first approach is wrong. Your second approach is good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe Linq is declarative enough?

```
var values = new[] { false, false, true, false };
bool notAllEqual = values.Any(x => x != values.First());
```

Alternatively:

```
var values = new[] { false, false, true, false };
bool allEqual = values.All(x => x == values.First());
if (!allEqual)
{
     // They are different
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For readability and understanding, I would swap the logic. When you check if values are different it's not clear - all values should be different (consider integer values 1, 2, 3), or values could be equal, but there is at least one different value (1, 2, 1)? When you check if all values are equal it's always clear.

And I would extract this logic to the nicely named method (you can even make it generic if you want):

```
public static bool AllEqual(params bool[] values)
{
    if (values.Length == 0)
       return true;

    var first = values[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
        if (values[i] != first)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

And usage

```
var notAllEqual = !AllEqual(value1, value2, value3, value4);
```

With *declarative* approach your code describes *what* you are doing instead of telling *how* and leaving the reader on its own to understand what.

---

Update: If you always deal with four boolean values, the simplest way to check if they are not all equal is

```
(value1 ^ value2) || (value2 ^ value3) || (value3 ^ value4)
```

But in terms of readability, any imperative approach is worse than declarative

Comment: `!=` easier to understand than `^`. Another option is `!(value1 == value2 && value2 == value3 && value3 == value4)`

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the bits and check

```
int value = (value1 ? 8 : 0) |
            (value2 ? 4 : 0) |
            (value3 ? 2 : 0) |
            (value4 ? 1 : 0);
return value != 0 && value != 15;
```

Comment: Nice one. A bit hacky and limited, but still... You've inspired me to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66190392/10958092).

Answer (score 1):

You said you want to check if your elements not

> all are true || all are false

Given a list
`var values = new List<bool> { value1, value2, value3, value4 };` of those elements, the closest representation in code would be:

```
var areDifferent = !(values.All(v => v == true) || values.All(v => v == false));
```

In terms of readability though, I would prefer:

```
var areEqual = values.All(v => v == true) || values.All(v => v == false);
```

and later check:

```
 if (!areEqual)
 {
     // Do something
 }
```

But that's just personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me a code smell, you might need to refactor the code instead of searching of a better way to display the booleans.

Without providing the actual code, you'll always get assumptions and not answers.

Anyhow, regarding to your specific question, you can create a `public static class` and use it as results tester to validate all kind of results through out your code. This way, you can reuse it, and also would be more readable.

for instance :

```
public static class Validate
{
    public static bool AreEqual(params bool[] values) => AreTrue(values) || AreFalse(values);
    
    public static bool AreTrue(params bool[] values) => values.All(x => x == true);
    
    public static bool AreFalse(params bool[] values) => values.All(x => x == false);
}
```

then use it like this :

```
bool value1 = false;
bool value2 = false;
bool value3 = true;
bool value4 = false;

if(Validate.AreEqual(value1 , value2 , value3 , value4))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This wont work for false values....if all the values are false, your method will return false, but the values are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Although personally, I prefer your first approach, the following works as well.

```
bool value1 = false;
bool value2 = false;
bool value3 = true;
bool value4 = false;

var values = new[] { value1, value2, value3, value4 };

bool areDifferent = values.Any(v => v) && values.Any(v => !v);
```

Comment: Great idea but this is probably the opposite direction that OP wants to go in terms of easy-to-understand

Answer (score 0):

[@phuclv's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65722255/10958092) approach made generic:

```
static bool AreDifferent(params bool[] values)
{
    var tmp = values.Select((value, index) => value ? 1 << index : 0).Aggregate((i, j) => i | j);
    return tmp != 0 && tmp != (1 << values.Length) - 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For understanding purpose, we can create a method and use if blocks.

```
public bool areDifferent(bool value1, bool value2, bool value3, bool value4)
{
    if(value1 == value2)
        if(value2 == value3)
            if(value3 == value4)
                return false;
                    
    return true;
}
```